# Tab doesn't complete words when pabbrev-mode is enabled

Tags: emacs

When I was typing a word, it showed suggestions in bracket, but hitting `[tab]` didn't do anything. I thought that is because the conflict between pabbrev-mode and the global usage of `[tab]`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs without an init file (`emacs -Q`) and then load the necessary file(s)?  If not, bisect your init file until you find what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by installing smart-tab and adding this line `(global-smart-tab-mode 1)` into `.emacs`.